# Playframework 1.2.1 Deploying Fails on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, playframework, failover

Hello guys can anyone help me, I've generate my play app with this command

```
play war mainindonesia -o ROOT --zip
```

`Resulting WAR files named ROOT.war, then i upload the files to my server under tomcat 6, in webapps directory. When deploying this error appear on LOG.

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/local/shared/tomcat/mainindonesia/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
08:11:14,939 INFO  ~ Starting /usr/local/shared/tomcat/mainindonesia/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/application
08:11:14,941 WARN  ~ Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.crud)
08:11:14,942 ERROR ~ Module crud will not be loaded because /usr/local/shared/tomcat/mainindonesia/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/modules/crud does not exist
08:11:14,942 WARN  ~ Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.secure)
08:11:14,942 ERROR ~ Module secure will not be loaded because /usr/local/shared/tomcat/mainindonesia/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/modules/secure does not exist
08:11:14,942 INFO  ~ Module secure is available (/usr/local/shared/tomcat/mainindonesia/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/application/modules/secure)
08:11:14,943 INFO  ~ Module crud is available (/usr/local/shared/tomcat/mainindonesia/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/application/modules/crud)
08:11:15,041 ERROR ~ Precompiled classes are missing!!
```

` can anyone tell me what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add servlet.jar to the war file, because it conflicts with tomcats implementation... you can compile against `javax/servlet/Servlet.class`, but not bundle it in the war.